Workday: Calculated Field to get Position ID out of Worktags in Journal Entries
Has anyone created a calc field to extract the Position ID from within the Additional Worktags box on the Journal Entries Business Object?
I need to be able to get the single position id for each journal entry line as I need to get amounts for specific funds (ex. Fed Share (Fund = 145) or Dept Share (Fund <> 145) by position id. Then I need to sum up the values for these two types of funding by position - there is a possibility that a worker could have multiple pay components but I want the values summed up by the specific fund and by position. If that makes sense.
Thanks!
Maria
I"m not sure where to start. I did add the worktags to my report but it brought in all the worktags for each position into one field. So there were two positions in one field etc. I just need the position ID to appear on my XML with the different funds and component codes by fund so that I can sum up the values by position. I am able to sum up the values by position on the earnings business object but I need the specific funds split out - so one amount for Fund = 145 and one amount for Fund <> 145.
I just don't know where to start.
